# Uipath can't read python script

Tags: python, codec, uipath

i'm trying to run a python script that filters and create pivot tables with excel, I run the script with the command prompt and it runs flawlessly but when i try it with Uipath it just wont run

I tried removing the comments, separating the code into two files, one with the import and the other with the rest of the code.

Creating the same file in the host computer and then copy pasting the code in it.

[image: this is the error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share the first byte of python script? It usually works fine. What you can also try is to copy and paste code in the property of Load Python Script activity. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: Found the error, there was a character in the script causing the exception, i erased it and now it works